# Adding backlight control for Raspberry Pi Zero 3.5 inch tft touch display (GPIO)

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, touchscreen, tft, backlight

Can somebody please help me how i can modify TFT35 display for backlight control with PWM (Raspberry Pi Zero 2 - GPIO 18). I found one solution on GitHub (https://github.com/wild-mustango/VenusOsTFT35) in readme (scroll little bit down) that project solve how to do it, but I can’t understand what I need to do if I want keep R5 on PCB board or there is other way how I can add backlight control? I very don’t understand how that PCB works. Thanks

IN SHORT:
I want to my touch display turn off 2 minutes after last touch and turn on when display will touched.

LINKS:

[all specs about TFT35 display](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display)

[raspberry pi zero 2 pinout](https://www.electrorules.com/raspberry-pi-zero-pinout-features-and-specifications)

[image: 35TFT touch display PCB]

[image: Connection display with Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W]

[image: specs of pins on 35TFT]
[image: spesc of chips on 35TFT PCB]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.